# import csv into MySQL database with python (MySQLdb.OperationalError)

Tags: python, mysql

I have trouble with import of csv data into MySQL tabel

The code I use looks like this :

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
import sys
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.2.20", user="xxx", password="xxxx", database="admin_mt")


cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE wp_dbo_iclock_transaction")
csv_data = csv.reader(open('wp_dbo_iclock_transaction.csv'))
header = next(csv_data)

print('Importing the CSV Files')
for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO wp_dbo_iclock_transaction (id, emp_code, punch_time, name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", row)

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
print('Done')
```

The error I get :

```
Importing the CSV Files
['1', '1', '11/01/2021 11:56', 'frfrgrgr r4']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Server Backup\time_import\import - Copy - Copy.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.execute(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '11/01/2021 11:56' for column 'punch_time' at row 1")
```

I've been looking for a way for days and still can't do it. Hope today I will find a good way.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that there is an issue with the format of the date/time string in the punch_time column of the CSV file. MySQL is expecting the date/time string to be in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, but the string in the CSV file is in the format MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM.

To resolve this issue, you can convert the date/time string in the CSV file to the correct format before inserting it into the database. You can use the datetime.strptime function from the datetime module to parse the date/time string and convert it to the correct format. Here's an example of how to do this:

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
from datetime import datetime

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.2.20", user="xxx", password="xxxx", database="admin_mt")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Truncate the table
cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE wp_dbo_iclock_transaction")

# Open the CSV file and skip the header row
csv_data = csv.reader(open('wp_dbo_iclock_transaction.csv'))
header = next(csv_data)

# Import the data from the CSV file
print('Importing the CSV Files')
for row in csv_data:
    # Convert the date/time string to the correct format
    punch_time = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # Insert the row into the database
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO wp_dbo_iclock_transaction (id, emp_code, punch_time, name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (row[0], row[1], punch_time, row[3]))

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
print('Done')
```

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the answer from @Mime, but an alternative method is to convert the MM/DD/YYYY date into MySQL's format in your INSERT statement using the [STR_TO_DATE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

```
cursor.execute("""
 INSERT INTO wp_dbo_iclock_transaction (id, emp_code, punch_time, name) 
 VALUES (%s,%s,STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%e/%c/%Y %H:%i'),%s)
""", row)
```

This way you don't have to convert the datetime value in Python, you can just pass `row` as the list of parameter values.

Both the solution by Mime and this solution should work equally well, and neither has a performance advantage. So it's up to your personal preference whether you'd rather do the conversion in Python or in SQL.

Comment: have error ( query = query % args
TypeError: float argument required, not bytes

 raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
MySQLdb.ProgrammingError: float argument required, not bytes )

Comment: I tested the code I showed above but I get no error. Are you getting that error on some different line of code?